# How to define tolerance level in CBC solver using pyomo's solverfactory?

Tags: pyomo, coin-or-cbc

I am trying to solve a MIP with CBC using pyomo's solver factory, however running into some infeasibility issues. I wanted to first try configuring the tolerance level and see if that works before diving deep into the data points that could cause the infeasibility.

However when I use this command, the cbc solver outputs an error:

```
options = {
            'tol': 0.0001
        }
        solver = SolverFactory(solver_type)
        solver.options.update(options)
```

Can anyone help me with the understanding how to define tolerance level in cbc? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, it depends a bit.  Assuming you are looking for the tolerance for a mixed integer program, the keyword for CBC is 'ratio'.

Here is a setup that runs 6 threads, max 20 seconds, ratio of 0.02 (2% gap)

```
### SOLVE
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
solver.options = {'sec': 20, 'threads': 6, 'ratio': 0.02}
results = solver.solve(mdl)
print(results)
```

There are several different types of syntax that are acceptable here...  You can pass the options in to the SolverFactory, etc...  but this works fine for me.

As another trick, I **always** get hung up on the correct keywords for these solvers....  If you have CBC installed properly, you can just go to the terminal, open CBC with the command `cbc`, which should give you the 'coin' prompt and type "?" to see the commands.  Then you can use the command and double '??' to get details.  This also works for `glpk` which is super helpful.

For instance:

```
% cbc
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.5 
Build Date: Dec  5 2021 

CoinSolver takes input from arguments ( - switches to stdin)
Enter ? for list of commands or help
Coin:?
In argument list keywords have leading - , -stdin or just - switches to stdin
One command per line (and no -)
abcd? gives list of possibilities, if only one + explanation
abcd?? adds explanation, if only one fuller help
abcd without value (where expected) gives current value
abcd value sets value
Commands are:
Double parameters:
 dualB(ound) dualT(olerance) primalT(olerance) primalW(eight) psi
 zeroT(olerance)
Branch and Cut double parameters:
 allow(ableGap) cuto(ff) inc(rement) integerT(olerance) preT(olerance)
 pumpC(utoff) ratio(Gap) sec(onds)
Integer parameters:
 force(Solution) idiot(Crash) maxF(actor) maxIt(erations) output(Format)
 randomS(eed) slog(Level) sprint(Crash)
Branch and Cut integer parameters:
 cutD(epth) cutL(ength) depth(MiniBab) hot(StartMaxIts) log(Level) maxN(odes)
 maxSaved(Solutions) maxSo(lutions) passC(uts) passF(easibilityPump)
 passT(reeCuts) pumpT(une) randomC(bcSeed) slow(cutpasses) strat(egy)
 strong(Branching) trust(PseudoCosts)
Keyword parameters:
 allC(ommands) chol(esky) crash cross(over) direction error(sAllowed)
 fact(orization) keepN(ames) mess(ages) perturb(ation) presolve
 printi(ngOptions) scal(ing) timeM(ode)
```